# JS Cypress finding row in table that contains value

Tags: javascript, cypress

I got table like this:

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj8S0.png)

Im trying to write a function that will go thru pages of the table to find row with ID that i passed, and then delete this row.

My function looks like this:

```
deleteRowByID(id){

    cy.get('nb-card-body').then(body =>{
        if(body.find('td:nth-child(2)').filter(":contains('15')").length > 0){
            cy.contains('td:nth-child(2)',id).parent('tr').find('.nb-trash').click()
        } else {
            cy.get('[aria-label="Next"]').click()
            this.deleteRowByID(id)
        }
    })    
}
```

if(body.find('td:nth-child(2)').filter(":contains('15')").length > 0)  - im getting column with ID's from the table and then i check if there is value that im looking for on this page of table.

In IF statement there is hard-coded '15' value. If i switch it to variable "id" it wont work since it will look for value = "id" instead of the variable value that i passed.
How can i fix it?

Comment: `.filter(\`:contains('${id}')\`)`

Comment: It would be easier to help answer this question if you included the HTML structure for the table or else we won't know how to best help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work if you just append the ID to your selector?

```
deleteRowByID(id){

    cy.get('nb-card-body').then(body =>{
        if(body.find('td:nth-child(2)').filter(":contains('" + id + "')").length > 0){
            cy.contains('td:nth-child(2)',id).parent('tr').find('.nb-trash').click()
        } else {
            cy.get('[aria-label="Next"]').click()
            this.deleteRowByID(id)
        }
    })    
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks a lot.
IDK why but i think i tried this before:
if(body.find('td:nth-child(2)').filter(":contains("+id+")").length > 0)
and this didnt work....

Comment: oh... i didnt use "+" signs before...